# Universal Command Sequence

Tags: code-golf, sequence, board-game

## Universal Command Sequence

### Definition

An \$n\$-maze is a \$n\times n\$ chessboard which has "walls" on some edges, and a "king" on the board that can move to the 4 adjacent cells, which cannot pass through any walls. Starting from any cell the king should be able to reach every cell on the board.

A command sequence is an array consisting of 4 distinct types of element (for example `[1,2,3,4,1,4,2,3,1,...]`). Each type of element means a direction of the movement of the king. A command sequence can be "applied to" a maze, if the king can traverse every cell on the board by following the command sequence. For example a command sequence `[up,right,down]` can be applied to a 2-maze that has no walls and the king is placed at the botton-left cell. If the king is going to pass through a wall or go outside the board, the command will be skipped.

### Challenge

For a given positive integer \$n\$, output a command sequence that can be applied to any \$n\$-maze. The existence of this sequence can be proved mathematically.<sup>See 1998 All-Russian Math Olympiad, Grade level 9, Day 1, Problem 4.</sup>

#### Input

A positive integer `n`. You can assume that `n>1`.

#### Output

An array consisting of 4 distince types of elements.

##### Python 3 validator

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##vVhLb9tGEL7zV0zpg8WaFmS76EFoCiRpguaQIo3d5qAI1opciYypXXZJWlUd/3Z3Zpak@BBtp4cKtETuY57ffDt0ussjrS4eQrmCqzeXVyPlw/uXH3y4fPO7N3UAP5HI3qkAXsBbkWTS4TFavpbqk0iSbBTo5FLKMPPB6C3flTurlas4SUiwaIzTJ15BItVIePATqPYUfYzMC6Ng5k7cOXwPIwWn5XoPTkC01ks0bVCCcOoZtPW9yNlS/EWnZnMf/@r5lTZQ@gOxqm6ztmgrBE5wd@VaEmf5KMvNaBmrKiDe7Hw69zyvLb2MEUmvwtWWXpo2KL3c1Zdexavto52vsyb/KkQyEj4sG8kgu27JItFLkNK5nVoOhtfioidrOSxLPFNWOXhligbuChVr1fUgwVQuERWdVP4Hp5KxSFOpwtGt17Uj2RuRFUtMxwEj/i8Dcpnlr7VSMsjj2zjfjTLCxF7alkoT7amrlOZnE5gCldEZop4H@AEHz7HA6P587jmt2mU9EmEY4FenfkX4BYsnQKTNy0qiRYd8NfDiBUxAqJAf2bjZ2Xxm2JZZMKd598ztRwN1cCmwGl49H1Rgnekr@QYFJ0MKgkMeTFCy9cA8RwEtpWANKzjkASl5roKTQwoqFgy/7FOrk/CjFEGERNTCrNkPziY@TBqiltqE0jRnWkDJcpmOOgBRWiU6EElDnV@p8EuBTmtHy67KmFZZs1y5fVVb055iAkcUcnHxmn7Amtstm9QjfgfwnjOo2FJAY2dprtfaUUdtv7Xnzj7o1ppOhBo2bKM4kXwIVsro6KTa7VGMJfoDgfeeSb70sUl1HidkIhLsEIzcSJWPbpBZGipqCNg2onESC2N26DLLqu3GAfIu86gQOm7H8DOWYNv6bBbPCfwsrX1Il/L7TmFweBtKu@nHgqdOcao3c9BiazWu31tbN0ythWXosgaFG3ErTSZHXOc@Ijb@oJuxaxSjnWPo7LGTamL4xlSnjdlQEWAj13YyjAmO2ORho7DpURHPUpgBjqBIe0Eo2QpVI7UOsHo5ycRI98gVg@RV@sHrm0G0Td3eoDM2KNRb9bRJA@eAXfBNJp08ZtI5m5TIVf6YSZP5wMlRTtZROnuGSZMnonTBJpl4HT3DpoHDpgzPt9h0IEwH23ERZxL@FEkh3xijzWjl/qaRR4OI7KdORqsp3CEs733YUBcUQq7hrsLq/Xduh48HmZOst9XSZ69Ziz85EEigPrgA7viLxhZ7tnLvbtCxex9/zub3LhfUDffsdt/cK48/Ij8q0Am/otRtlD0EbIHa49LZExmFuyQJFEtPMRKnWymnRj/2WGVMKkkFdvq2LJtvMtzi00n0zNbOaUDhqf6xgZiap5pvfKzb88lFD53vJzs15NRB1KzcSzydpAokrAQGJAStGH9seEauMQySe9aC9/h9P/6sXH9A3lVpIqYnK5J8@lndPW01JnZ8QKL3@PFYz5aZb59@GOwWDGwuvA5lt/co2xeSTVa6DZ17FcUZ4CXgViRxiLts0KgKOofxA7@7W0DG/0jr1F2ttUingCBsMzpx6ZQUd3mVGA1h4/fYjXllChd@m2TurboZ2jf3He/h@PjYub7@IxNrOb6@hl@0Os7p8JSQRxIiKbCnGcNHmSYCEbAggxewjfMIVLFZYoO0UAsfFkVK32QZ/ZIh9Mtqy@U7XRiWuaIbmXA4MxzB1@eNFCrjyUAbREWqVRir9Z5ofGa@BRpdSrNrNxsarkJtZaEehKfKiYyobiipqTAiRwDwVt42hnfIovjGDrrI0yKHTG@waVFYxxtBGkEscYb1VPLp1f5GwmCqXZ8Yolsu4/HYHcObv8UmRTYpKNBTZ7FYOHsUXHQhMDmAgLOD6T8/mPuL4byjDLwu@JrwZe/PeZwuggUbeIQfuMIQwmsdSvhVJqnjnML1dZOKCDQvMYwUamyBhUFKwCKWNuDLHUeQJwMSgmFbF5gNlUt7XiwpjyyOToJ4LMfw1mAzJNQOG1phcsJBilRrc3FDj4FQNc/hqNHFOgKJjzv7NjEqMlpW4ynIe1jBVK1wsEAJ3th69anmNPKJWQioDlIEJEK19GarcdCIXQYLpKiFxSXy1AJzzBaUyOZ/JVjaYaiEMog3gt50crmmkrrScKPwRNhGsiy2baUS32uIK0gB9rcL2oOBipUwO1sItHpxtjhmGNZbj4mVYgJvjbepw5lUSGMXDjM1AeDHucNMPfuBzzrnFaVt6hzB0dcj5/QEj@LyHuz9V3xynNFR/b6G/e8pfOVH1mzxwlHskDuHMpLKln/WLI2MDhIuu/o08dmZ1Oi1ERtbnkjjuqpRhlJHPtUxB5j@7UZJJVlVp8G2wogCWWyUT2nyQKxypK0VduJZVMFkG@mkTyhjeB3JADsJJhM0kFoC7H@sWMIG/zfDKhs7SKUP/wI) Test your generated sequence here. Usage tips can be found in the footer.

---

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf). Shortest code wins.

Comment: Sandbox link: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges/24244#24244

Comment: [Related: _Shortest universal maze exit string_](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/53310/52210): sequence to go from any variable start to any variable exit in any 3x3 maze. This challenge will be quite a bit harder I assume, since it's not a hard-coded 3x3 maze but \$N\times N\$ based on the input \$N\$ instead. (The 'variable start to exit' versus 'visit all cells' shouldn't make a̶n̶y̶?̶  too much difference.)

Answer (score 11):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 7 bytes

```
s^S4^5*
```

We could construct a universal sequence of length \$2^{2n(n-1)} ⋅ n^2 ⋅ (2n^2 - 2) < 5^{n^2}\$. Start with the empty sequence; then for each of the at most \$2^{2n(n-1)}\$ mazes and \$n^2\$ possible starts, imagine following all the previously appended commands to get a new location, and append \$2n^2 - 2\$ more commands representing a complete traversal of that maze from that new location.

But, since we know we could construct it, we don’t have to actually do it. Instead, just concatenate all length \$5^{n^2}\$ sequences of \$1, 2, 3, 4\$. Since we just proved at least one of those sequences is universal, so is their concatenation.